# VS deploy looking for WP device instead of W10M

Tags: visual-studio, deployment, uwp, windows-phone-8.1

I've been trying to deploy my UWP app on a W10M phone via a USB connection, but VS is trying to deploy it into a WP8.1 device, which as expected, fails. The following are informative about the situation:

- The app is being compiled with a target of **Creators Update 1703** (b15063), and a minimum of **November Update 1511** (b10586).
- The app is not migrated from a WP8.1 project.
- The target device OS version is **10.0.15063.297 (Insider)**.
- Development tools are on, tried re-enabling it, no change of weather.
- Tried both USB 3 and USB 2, neither are working.
- The phone is visible to my PC, both in the device manager and the file explorer, and it's fully functional for data transport.
- The interop is not unlocked, but *New Capability Engine*, *Full Filesystem Access* is unlocked, and the original *NDTKSvc* is restored.
- The IDE is **Visual Studio Community 2017 (15.1)**.
- This is the first error message: [image: The First Error]
- And so is the output: `DEP6200: Bootstrapping failed. Device cannot be found. SmartDeviceException - Deployment failed because no device was detected. Make sure a device is connected and powered on.  [0x80131500]`

Thanks.

Comment: Did you select ARM in project configuration on top and next drop down as Device?

Comment: @AVK yes. It's configured for ARM-Debug

Comment: Did you unlock your phone for development?

Comment: @AVK as mentioned in the main topic, it's a W10M device and the development mode is enabled.

Comment: Have you tried deploying to the same phone from another pc? I got this dialog too when my phone wasn't connected. Maybe.. Has your computer enabled the developer mode too?

Comment: And well I got it when my phone was locked while deploying to it. Make sure it stays unlocked until the deployment is done.

Comment: @MarianDolinský I have no other development PC in hand. My PC has Dev mode enabled. And my phone stays unlocked during the deployment.

Comment: That's weird, maybe repairing/reinstalling Visual Studio could help..

Comment: Can this app be deployed to your local machine successfully? Did you have another phone for testing? What is your testing phone?

Comment: @SunteenWu-MSFT Yes, it successfully deploys on local machine and a Mobile emulator. The only existing problem is with USB deployment.